# Zero-Initialize array member in initialization list

Tags: c++, initialization, initialization-list, array-initialization

I have a class with an array member that I would like to initialize to all zeros.

```
class X
{
private:
    int m_array[10];
};
```

For a local variable, there is a straightforward way to zero-initialize (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065774/c-c-initialization-of-a-normal-array-with-one-default-value)):

```
int myArray[10] = {};
```

Also, the class member `m_array` clearly needs to be initialized, as default-initializing ints will just leave random garbage, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7760291/default-initialization-of-c-member-arrays).

However, I can see two ways of doing this for a member array:

With parentheses:

```
public:
    X()
    : m_array()
    {}
```

With braces:

```
public:
    X()
    : m_array{}
    {}
```

Are both correct? Is there any difference between the two in C++11?

Comment: How are you testing? When compiling with `gcc -std=c++98`, I get a message "warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]", without even having to add `-pedantic`.

Comment: I just quickly checked on [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/Q8jLzb) with the C++ 4.8.1 option, I don't know what flags they used, so I removed my claim.

Comment: Visual Studio 2013 outputs a [spurious](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24122006/vs2013-default-initialization-vs-value-initialization) warning message for the second option: `warning C4351: new behavior: elements of array 'X::m_array' will be default initialized`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Initialising any member with `()` performs value initialisation.

Initialising any class type with a default constructor with `{}` performs value initialisation.

Initialising any other aggregate type (including arrays) with `{}` performs list initialisation, and is equivalent to initialising each of the aggregate's members with `{}`.

Initialising any reference type with `{}` constructs a temporary object, which is initialised from `{}`, and binds the reference to that temporary.

Initialising any other type with `{}` performs value initialisation.

Therefore, for pretty much all types, initialisation from `{}` will give the same result as value initialisation. You cannot have arrays of references, so those cannot be an exception. You *might* be able to construct arrays of aggregate class types without a default constructor, but compilers are not in agreement on the exact rules. But to get back to your question, all these corner cases do not really matter for you: for your specific array element type, they have the exact same effect.

Answer (score 16):

The types of initialization can be kind of tedious to go through, but in this case it is trivial. For:

```
public:
    X()
    : m_array()
    {}
```

since the *expression-list* between the parentheses are empty, value-initialization occurs. Similarly for:

```
public:
    X()
    : m_array{}
    {}
```

list-initialization occurs, and subsequently value-initialization since the *brace-init-list* is empty.

---

To give a more comprehensive answer, let's go through §8.5 of N4140.

> 12. If no initializer is specified for an object, the object is
>       default-initialized. When storage for an object with automatic or
>       dynamic storage duration is obtained, the object has an *indeterminate
>       value*, and if no initialization is performed for the object, that
>       object retains an indeterminate value until that value is replaced
>       (5.17).

This *indeterminate value* is what you refer to as garbage values.

> 6. To *zero-initialize* an object or reference of type `T` means:
>
>    — if T is an array type, each element is zero-initialized
> 7. To *value-initialize* an object of type `T` means:
>
>    — if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type ... then the object is default-initialized; ...
>
>    — if T is an array type, then each element is value-initialized;
>
>    — otherwise, the object is zero-initialized.
> 8. The semantics of initializers are as follows. ...
>      — If the initializer is a (non-parenthesized) *braced-init-list*, the object or reference is list-initialized (8.5.4).
>
>    — If the initializer is (), the object is value-initialized.

So far it's clear that value initialization will make each element of the array zero since `int` is not a class type. But we have not yet covered list initialization and aggregate initialization, since an array is an aggregate.

§8.5.4:

> 3. List-initialization of an object or reference of type `T` is defined as follows:
>
>    — If T is an aggregate, aggregate initialization is performed (8.5.1).

And back to §8.5.1:

> 7. If there are fewer *initializer-clauses* in the list than there
>      are members in the aggregate, then each member not explicitly
>      initialized shall be initialized from its *brace-or-equal-initializer*
>      or, if there is no *brace-or-equal-initializer*, from an empty
>      initializer list (8.5.4).

And we end with §8.5.4 again:

> 3. List-initialization of an object or reference of type `T` is defined as follows:
>
>    — Otherwise, if the initializer list has no elements, the object is value-initialized.

Since traversing the (draft) standard can take breath out of you, I recommend [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/) as it breaks it down pretty good.

#### Relevant links:

cppreference:

- [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization)
- [value initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization)

Draft standard:

- [N4140](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/master/papers/n4140.pdf)

Answer (score -1):

Parentheses work in C++98, and are calling for zero initialization, which is what you want. I verified on gcc 4.3. Edit: removed incorrect statement about C++11. I also confirmed that empty braces perform empty-list-initialization using clang 3.4 with -std=c++11.

Comment: The part about C++11 is incorrect. The `{}` in `: m_array{}` is a *braced-init-list* (not a `std::initializer_list`) and can very well be empty. This empty *braced-init-list* performs value-initialization of the array, which leads to zero-initialization of the `int` elements.